# Having trouble with Simulator but not device

Tags: ios, ios6, controller, segue, simulator

Im using the latest ios 6.1 on both phone and simulator. On the phone everything works fine, but when I go to the simulator it's not. The worst error is the segues. I'm performing a segue like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToLogin" sender:self];
```

On the phone it's fine but in the simulator I get the NSInvalidArgumentException which tells me that i have no segue with identifier "ToLogin", which i've checked I have on the storyboard (and phone is working)

Also when I change the initial view controller it doesn't matter on the simulator, I always go to the same place.

Any thoughts on what could be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: have you checked the case of the identifier?

Comment: have you tried resetting the simulator? Clean All Targets in xcode?

Comment: Try restoring the sim. iPhone Simulator > Delete all Content and Settings

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I deleted all content and made a clean and it worked! put it as an answer so I can give you cred!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restoring the simulator. `iPhone Simulator > Delete all Content and Settings`. This often works when having unexplainable sim errors.